# Lisp weird new line before print

Tags: linux, lisp, common-lisp

When I'm trying to print some text from terminal using "clisp hello.lisp" (where "hello.lisp" is name of my program) then new line is added before right output (so before "hello world"). Why it happens and how can I change this? In other languages like Python or Ruby there is no newline in the same code.

```
(print "hello world")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prin1 instead of print:

```
(prin1 "Hello world")
```

> There's also a function named prin1. This is same as print except it
>   doesn't add a newline.

Answer (score 3):

> Why it happens

It happens because the function `PRINT` is specified to do that.

> and how can I change this?

You can't. Just use a different function for printing: WRITE-STRING, WRITE-LINE, WRITE or PRIN1.

WRITE-LINE prints the string and then prints a newline.

> In other languages like Python or Ruby there is no newline in the same code.

Since these are different programming languages, the same code will not run in Python and Ruby.